# How to concatenate vertical cell values in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new to SQL and I would like to know if there is a way to concatenate the cell values.

For instance, I would like to transform the table below:

```
+---------------------+------------------+
|   student1          |    Mathematics   |
|   student1          |    Science       |
|   student1          |    English       |
|   student2          |    Mathematics   |
|   student2          |    English       |
+---------------------+------------------+
```

Into a table that looks like this:

```
+---------------------+------------------------------------+
|   student1          |    Mathematics, Science, English   |
|   student2          |    Mathematics, English            |
+---------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `group_concat()`:

```
select student, group_concat(subject, ', ') as subjects
from t
group by student;
```

In SQL Server, the equivalent uses `string_agg()`:

```
select student, string_agg(subject, ', ') as subjects
from t
group by student;
```

Comment: hey sorry for the confusion. actually I would like to know how to write it in t-sql.

Comment: @AneeshaA . . . You need to tag your questions *correctly*.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `group_concat()`

```
select col1, group_concat(col2,', ') from tablename
group by col1
```

Comment: hey sorry for the confusion. actually I would like to know how to write it in t-sql.

Comment: @AneeshaA, what is your dbms version